# How to put up a server with a lot of connections

Tags: mysql, installation, server-side

I need to put up a server with many and many connections, approximately 1 million at the same time.

I need to know how to do it and what technologies to use.
I have messages from users (i'll use xmpp protocol), and they have to pass from a server, so if 1 million people at the same time use the same server it will crash. And the users will use database (mysql?) for registration.

So...how do I set the server so that it doesn't crash? What kind of server i'll use (apache mysql server...)? And what to do for the database to hold all that traffic? queries won't take too much time?

I've read those documents for configuring mysql and they don't suggest me to have more then 1000 connections.. [link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/01/06/mysql-high-number-connections-per-secon/)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you forced to use mysql and apache? I don't know all facts about your needs but i guess that node.js and mongodb should be a good choice. Mongo is quiet fast cause of delayed inserts and the non relational layout.

Comment: mongodb is nosql Marc. For messagges and registrations is better a sql db. No?

Comment: Depends on your special need. I guess that nosql is quiet nice for registration data (cause it's just only one key necessary and you can store whatever you want). For messages i would use a more powerful dbms which less of features - but this decision you have to make concerning your concept.

Comment: Facebook what kind of database and server use? i cannot find it on google

Comment: ps. it's possible to use python and not php?

Comment: you can write it in your preferred language. but if you want to save servers you should spend some time in evaluation :) Facebook is using PHP and they started with their own version because of heavy load on the community version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up loadbalancers(like nginx, haproxy) which send users to the right server, and you can build a cloud: webserver cluster, database cluster behind load balancers. You can also set up a backup server and rsync which can restore your data if anything goes wrong.

check digitalocean tutorials, its worth a shot:
[haproxy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-http-load-balancing-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

Comment: could you give me links to learn what you wrote? because I understand what you said but i really don't know how to do it.

Comment: mmh, but Facebook and similar apps use a method like this?